# Stack two frames, a frame with rows and columns and a frame without

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a window with Tkinter that has a frame with a grid of labels on the top and a frame with two buttons on the bottom.

I am able to create a frame with labels on top and a frame with buttons on bottom, but whenever I try to lay out the labels in a grid I run into problems and nothing shows up.

To summarize.
I can create two frames, one on top, one on bottom.
I can create a frame with a grid system.
I cannot create two frames where one has a grid system and one does not.

Can anyone show me how to get the layout I want?

I am following the guide and using code from [Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/#using-events-and-event-handlers).

The code I am trying to use is below.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)

    for j in range(0, 2):
        frame = tk.Frame(
            master=window,
            relief=tk.RAISED,
            borderwidth=1
        )
        frame.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=5, pady=5)

        label = tk.Label(master=frame, text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}")
        label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

frame2 = tk.Frame(master=window, height=25, bg="blue")
frame2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are not creating *a frame with grid of labels*.  You are creating *grid of frames with a label inside each*.  Try creating `frame` outside the for loops and then create grid of labels inside it using `.grid()`.  Then lay out `frame` using `.pack()`.

Comment: I am extremely new to Tkinter. I tried doing what you said and at least the window appears, but the grid isn't working correctly as everything is just in one column. What I changed was put the frame outside of the loop and add label.grid(~~~) inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not create *a frame with grid of labels*, but *grid of frames with a label inside each*.

Create `frame` outside the for loops and the grid of labels inside it using `.grid()`.  Then lay out `frame` using `.pack()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# create the top frame
frame = tk.Frame(master=window)
frame.pack()

# create grid of labels inside frame
for i in range(3):
    window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)
    window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=50)

    for j in range(0, 3):
        label = tk.Label(master=frame, text=f"Row {i}\nColumn {j}", bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED, padx=5, pady=5)
        label.grid(row=i, column=j)

# create bottom frame
frame2 = tk.Frame(master=window, height=25, bg="blue")
frame2.pack(fill=tk.X)

window.mainloop()
```

The output:

[image]